# Default argument and empty list initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor, default-arguments, list-initialization

Consider the following code, of a simple class with a constructor taking an argument with a default value.

```
// Version 1
template <class T>
struct object1 {
    using type = T;
    constexpr object1(const type& val = type()): value(val) {}
    type value;
};

// Version 2
template <class T>
struct object2 {
    using type = T;
    constexpr object2(const type& val = {}): value(val) {}
    type value;
};

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using type = /* Something */;
    object1<type> x1;
    object2<type> x2;
    auto value1 = x1.value;
    auto value2 = x2.value;
    // Is there certain types for which value1 and value2 will be different?
    return 0;
}
```

Are the two versions of the constructor equivalent (will always produce the same result for any `T`), or they are different?

If they are different, could you provide an example of `T` for which the two would lead to different results?

Comment: why so verbose? Do i miss something or is the question basically about the difference between `T t = {};` and `T t = T();` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. Second variant relies on implicitness of T's default constructor:

```
class foo
{
   public: explicit foo() {}
};

object1<foo> of{}; // ok
object2<foo> of{}; // error
```

Also I think it is not a good idea to call a copy constructor from a temporary instead of calling a default constructor without a temporary. That is it would be better to implement separate constructors:

```
template <class T>
struct object1 {
    using type = T;
    constexpr object1(void): value{} {}

    constexpr object1(const type& val): value{val} {}

    type value;
};
```